# Building an app with google maps/apple maps embedded - need assistance

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

Apologies if this has already been asked! I have outsourced the development of an app (IOS and Android) that has a maps function built in. When the app is opened it brings up the users current location on a map. The second half of the page is meant to show the actual address, and nearby addresses.

Example

10 Commerce Street, Auckland, NZ
9 Commerce Street, Auckland, NZ
1/11 Commerce Street, Auckland, NZ
Mobil Petrol Station, 12 Commerce Street, Auckland, NZ

This part doesnt work at all and is only showing landmarks. The email from the devloper states

"The project we are using given url for finding nearst location. we already have done a lot of R&D and found that below url better than others. if you suggest any other url then plz let me know.

http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=&lng=&radius="

This URL still only has placemarks.

I really need help! Ive seen it done in other apps and I was hoping it was something google offered. Basically im hoping for an API that I can send to the developer to use.

I am not a technical person at all so hope this makes a little sense :)

Thanks heaps in advance

James

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API can do that! It's called "Geocoding". You can find more info and API reference at https://developers.google.com/maps/

(EDIT: Now, after a little skimming; I think you should check "JavaScript API" part specifically...)

Comment: Really? Then why are my developers so useless? :)

Comment: Lol.. There is no useless developer; just lazy ones :p

Comment: Haha... sorry, but it is funny! Yeah, you've gotta be careful who you trust with your outsourcing... it sounds like these guys aren't very experienced. `MKMapView` on iOS is pretty straight-forward, and I'm sure these something equivalent that's easy to use on Android, too... ; P

Comment: Thanks heaps guys. Ill go back to my developers. Any link to an android equivalent would be awesome.

Comment: The link I gave you has Android/iOS both API for Google Maps already!